# My app suddenly shows fullscreen-ADS.

Tags: android

Since some weeks I randomly got fullscreen ads on my test phone while testing MY APP. Till now I thought it's another app causing those. But now I saw the same behaviour on another phone. When browsing my app, suddenly this pops up:

[This ad shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/299pr.jpg)

I integrated **not a single ad library**. But a lot of third party ones. Is it possible that they are causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You're using a 3rd party library (that isn't a well known one) without reading the source code looking for stuff like this?  That's a really bad idea.  Never trust a library you haven't code audited.

Comment: If you add the list of used libraries maybe someone could spot the bad one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those third party libraries make money through showing the ads on your application. Its their way of getting payed for the free library

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the app **Peel Remote** was causing those annoying fullscreen ads. Which came randomly anywhere *in my app*.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7hc0.jpg)

Fortunately my app is not the guilty one.

Thanks 'yall.